# In RaphaelJS, how do I move around individual nodes in a path?

Tags: javascript, raphael

Is there an array containing those?

Also, is it also possible to add nodes in an existing path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the path. No, there's no array, just the path string. You  can of course write higher level code that keeps tracks of nodes in arrays from which you generate path strings.

A simple implementation would be something like:

```
function Polygon (nodes) {
    if (nodes instanceof Array) this.nodes = nodes;
    else this.nodes = [];
}

Polygon.prototype.draw = function () {
    var path = "M" + this.nodes[0][0] + "," + this.nodes[0][1];
    for (var i=1; i<this.nodes.length; i++) {
        path += "L" + this.nodes[i][0] + "," + this.nodes[i][1];
    }
    path += "Z";
    return path;
}
```

Then you would do:

```
var p = new Polygon([[100,100],[100,200],[200,200],[200,100]]);

var pp = paper.path(p.draw());

// Modify node:
p.nodes[2] = [300,300];
pp.attr('path',p.draw());

// Add node:
p.nodes.push([250,150]);
pp.attr('path',p.draw());
```

Of course you can be more creative with the API you implement. For example, `polygon.draw()` can automatically update a linked Raphael Element. The code above is just a simple example of the basic idea.